# How to not delete session data on logout in ember simple auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Is there way how to not remove data from session on logout?

I need to make ajax to invalidate token and then redirect to page outside ember. While waiting for ajax to resolve user sees how data from session are removed because of live binding. If I will not  wait for ajax to return the request became aborted. I also tried not to use invalidate method on authorizer but that brakes multi tab support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make an ajax request when the session is invalidated you can implement a custom authenticator and override the `invalidate` method: http://ember-simple-auth.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Authenticators-Base-invalidate